# check if a string is encrypted r not in c#

Tags: c#

How to find is password is encrypted (SHA256 algorithm) or not through C#. I have a table like customer with password column. I need to find which passwords are encrypted and which not encrypted in c#.net

Comment: Any 32 bytes string is a hash from a plain text.. There is only 2^(32*8) possibility so...

Comment: "Encrypted" and "hashed" are not at all the same thing.  Which one are you asking about?  If it's "encrypted" then try decrypting it.  If it's hashed, then it's hashed.  You can't de-hash.  What's the actual problem you're trying to solve, anyway?  This sounds like a potential XY Problem.

Comment: There is no way to differenciate a 32byte plain text from a hash as the plain text is a possible hash. So either the string is not 32byte and it's not an hash or it's 32byte and it's both an hash or/and a password.

Comment: If you are storing both encrypted and unencrypted passwords you have bigger problems than working out which is which. I'd suggest only ever storing hashed passwords, then you don't need to work it out. Regarding the downvotes, your question is rather vague, and doesn't include details of what you have tried already, what particular issue you have encountered etc. Perhaps take the SO [tour] and read [ask]

Comment: a quick and dirty way to check this is to check the length of the password, sha256 creates hashes of the same length every time. assuming that a non-hashed password can't be this length though.

Comment: @Lennart, yep it's a 32bytes, so as string should be 64.

Comment: And the char must be `[a-fA-F0-9]` or for base64 `[0-9a-zA-Z+/]`.

Comment: Will hashin this column into a new one androp the old one enought to solve your issue? I mean you have either (Hash or Not Hash). Hashing it will give (Hash Hash or Hash). So when User enter an input you hashit and compare with the column if it fail you hash it a second time to have an Hash Hash.

Answer (score 0):

A SHA256 Hash is a 32Byte[] in string it **can be** 64char lenght string.
Depending on the base the valid char **may be** `[a-fA-F0-9]` or for base64 `[0-9a-zA-Z+/]`.

But that's not enought as `FOOBAR01` copy past 8 time is both a password and a hash from `2^(32*8)` possible plain text.

You should just force your user to change the password on next connection and hash them all this time.

You can also take the issue from the other side.

In your login function, compare the input password with the database value. If it match then you have an Unhash password and can convert it.

Or it doesnt and you try to compare the Hashed input and the database value, 
If match you have a hased password and the user should log in. 
Else no password match, login failed.